# Changing Login text to Image + creating drop down for My account, Wishlist, Sign out and more.

Tags: magento2, login, toplinks

A similar question was asked for Magento 1.9, trying it for Magento 2.0 broke my site. Looking for a more specific answer.

I am using Magento 2.1.5 -- I want to remove the Top links from all pages. Then using a block, i want to place a User Image(.png) or Icon next to shopping cart to create a drop down to login. If the customer is logged in, i want the drop down to have a list showing "My account", "My wishlist", "Other random links", and "Logout".

How would i go about doing this? Can i use CSS to dress this pop up?

Heres a picture of what i am looking to create. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

[image]